# What is the relation/difference between axiomatic and denotational semantics one one side, and the data flow analysis(DFA) on the other sied?

Tags: semantics, dfa, denotational-semantics

I am supposed to write a small paper about DFA in OOP for a CS class in theory. But I am required to connect that (DFA) to axiomatic and denotational semantics!
I read few resources about axiomatic/denotational semantics but no one is talking specifically about their relation to Data Flow Analysis.
Can you please guide me about that, or at least guide me to a book, chapter or a paper that talks about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textbook that might be most relevant to your question is [Principles of Program Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540654100)
by Nielson, Nielson and Hankin. It does cover dataflow analysis and its relationship to denotational semantics. It does not deal with axiomatic semantics though.